# Travelling in and out of the Schengen area with a Fiktionsbescheinigung

Tags: croatia

My residence card has expired and I applied for extension and have gone for the appointment. I have also being given by the German authorities a *Fiktionsbescheinigung* with the third option ticked which says that the expired residence permit is still valid. The worst case here is that my old residence card was stolen with my wallet and I went to the police and they told me since i have gone for renewal and I have the ficktionbeschinigung- it is okay.

However, I need to travel to Croatia (non-schengen area) for an EU volunteer work which I am a major organiser. I hold a third country passports so my passport cannot get me through.

What would you advise. I decided to take a train but as I know there are always checks at the Croatian border.

What would you advise guys. I really need to go for this otherwise i loose a great opportunity

Comment: *I hold a third country passports so my passport cannot get me through.* - which country is your passport from?

Comment: It should not be a problem to travel in and out of the Schengen area with your Fiktionsbescheinigung. I would be more conserned (I am not sure) if Croatia will let you enter with one.

Comment: My passport is from Ghana

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo i have been able to enter , the border officers only wanted to know what i am going to do and also scanned my passport and checked the fiktionbeschinigung as well. And i got my passport stamped.Am in Croatia now. Thanks guys